# Displaying WordPress posts from post and custom post type in custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type named `resources`. *Resources* use a custom taxonomy `resource`.

When I originally planned my WordPress website, I assumed that I would only ever need to use the resource taxonomy for resources. Well, it turns out that I write posts that are resources that don't need to use the custom post type that resources uses. (Resources template is used for files, etc).

The code below is how I am displaying all of my Resource posts. I get a header for each category once and then list the posts that are in that category. I want all the resources on a single page, nicely organized. The problem is that I need to include posts in the list as well... I've tried editing this code and its not working.

```
        <?php           
        $custom_terms = get_terms('resource');

        foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            $args = array('post_type' => 'resources',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'resource',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                    ),
                ),
             );

             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
             if($loop->have_posts()) {
                echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2><ul>';

                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                endwhile;
                    echo '</ul>';
             }
        }
        ?>
```

I'm assuming that whatever I've been doing has been missing something really easy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to include the `post` post type, it needs to be added to the [`post_type` parameter for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters):

```
        $args = array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'resources' ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'resource',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
         );
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work. I'll try and run it again and see if it pans out.